# Extracting the elements from the consecutive pattern in the dataframe vector

Tags: r, sequence, seq

I have a dataframe of more than 30,000 values as follows

```
1   qw
2   as
3   we
4   er
5   rt
6   @@@@
7   @@@@
8   @@@@
9   @@@@
10  as
11  df
12  fg
13  gh
14  hj
```

I want to extract the values at location index 1,3,5,10,12,14,19,21,23 and so on. As a beginner I know extraction of value using `seq(first, last, by=)` but I am not able to do slicing as per the above pattern.

```
1   qw
3   we
5   rt
10  as
12  fg
14  hj
```

Comment: Hey, I think you need to specify this question a bit. I assume based on this pattern the next value is 19?

Comment: Yes right @JAQuent

Comment: Please explain _in words_ the logic of your sequence.

Comment: My desire output should be based on the sequence of first three value with common difference of 2 and then difference of 5, then three values at difference of 2 and then difference of 5 and so on

Comment: Within the two first chunks the difference is 2, but within the chunk `19,22,25` the difference is 3. How can we then possibly guess what _so on_ is?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I have corrected it thank you

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having something nested like this would work for you:

```
> rep(seq(1, 5, 2), 3) + rep(seq(0, 18, 9), each = 3)
[1]  1  3  5 10 12 14 19 21 23
```

For more values:

```
nMax <- 30000

seq1 <- seq(1, 5, 2)
seq2 <- rep(seq(0, nMax, 9))

rep(seq1, length(seq2)) + rep(seq2, each = 3)
```

Comment: but I have a sequence of more than 30,000.

Comment: If that is what you're looking for, please accept the answer or try to give us more information.